# Object Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I need  to implement animation in my project,
Moving a view from left lower corner to right lower corner.in the same time another view need to be come from Upper side to center of the Screen, How can i implement it using Object animation.

Comment: take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Answer (score 1):

I use [View Property Animator](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html):

```
 myView.animate().x(500).y(500);
```

I found it simple. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all that you want to achieve (just moving views around), then you can do that with a few lines of code, without using xmls. Lets take the example of moving a button to the right by say 100 pixels.

```
// Get the view
TranslateAnimation slideRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200f, 0, 0);

// logoutButton is the view that is to be animated
logoutButton.setAnimation(slideRight);

// or 
logoutButton.startAnimation(slideRight); // to immediately start the animation
```

Refer [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can create animation xml files, and load them for your views.
refer to [view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).
Animation XML file:

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="700" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
           android:fromXScale="1.4"
           android:toXScale="0.0"
           android:fromYScale="0.6"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400"
           android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="0"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```

load the animation for your views

```
ImageView spaceshipImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spaceshipImage);
Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
spaceshipImage.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
```